# split list of column values into rows

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a csv in the following format:

```
col1  col2               col3            col4  
'1'   ['Ron', 'jeremy']  [54.5, 78.8]    '1_data'  
'2'   ['roy', 'susan']   [56.7, 34.6]    '2_data'
```

i want the csv to be in following format:

```
col1  col2     col3  col4  
'1'   'Ron'    54.5  '1_data'  
'1'   'jeremy' 78.8  '1_data'  
'2'   'roy'    56.7  '2_data'
'2'   'susan'  34.6  '2_data'
```

I have achieved this by using 'pandas' but have to use 'csv' module of python3 to do this.
Any help would be helpful.

Comment: could be there list presentations with more that 2-items ? like `['Ron', 'jeremy', 'some value']`

Comment: yes any number of values, but length of the lists of col2 and col3 are same.

Answer (score 0):

With list *slicing* and `zip()` function:

```
with open('yourfile.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=' ')

    for i, r in enumerate(reader):
        if i == 0:
            print(r)    # header columns
        else:
            row = [r[0], r[-1]]  # resulting record containing 1st and last column
            slice_len = len(r) - 2
            col2, col3 = [r[p:p+slice_len//2] for p in range(1, slice_len + 1, 2)]
            for pair in zip(col2, col3):
                row[1:-1] = list(map(lambda v: v.strip("[],"), pair))
                print(row)
```

The current output (for demonstration):

```
['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
["'1'", "'Ron'", '54.5', "'1_data'"]
["'1'", "'jeremy'", '78.8', "'1_data'"]
["'2'", "'roy'", '56.7', "'2_data'"]
["'2'", "'susan'", '34.6', "'2_data'"]
```

---

Now, all you need here is to delare `writer = csv.writer(<your_new_file>)` and call `writer.writerow(row)` instead of `print(row)`

Comment: Not working, i'm getting the following error:  ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @fnatic9, it's working with your current input. Check your manual errors and make sure you've posted the actual input content

Comment: @fnatic9, also, check your file for trailing whitespaces